# Is Draco portrayed in the canon books as good-looking?

Tags: harry-potter, adaptation-comparison

In fan-fiction, Draco-Harry and Draco-Hermione pairings are very common. Their popularity is evidenced by the fact that this very site has specific tags for them. This is often attributed to Draco being cute.

And there's no doubt that *Tom Felton*, who plays Draco in the films, is good-looking. But is there any canonical information in the books or related material about Draco's appearance? Is he conventionally attractive? Or not so much, like most of the Slytherins we hear about save Zabini and Riddle?

Comment: To be fair, we don't have a lot of information regarding Hermione. They could just be similarly unattractive. True, the standard assumption about main female characters is that they look like Emma Watson, but all we technically know about Hermoine is that her hair is bushy.

Comment: @MishaR, Victor Krum described her as good-looking, so she's probably at least modestly attractive.  That still leaves a lot of room for variation though.  Fan-fiction is always going to place the author's favored characters towards the upper end of the scale, however, so I rather suspect that saying Draco is a popular character because he is cute is confusing cause and effect.  (Well, up to the point where the movies came out, I guess.)

Comment: @MishaR - Perhaps, but it's *Draco* who's popular. That's why you both Draco-Hermione and Draco-Harry are rather popular.

Comment: It could just be that Draco is a very visible and prominent character in the book which is why fan fiction is written around him.

Comment: @JoeW - Maybe, but there's a widespread belief that Malfoy is cute. I'll cite some things if I have to. Also Drarry and Dramonione are much more common that Harry and Hermione, Ron and Hermione, Hermione and Ginny.

Comment: [Evil is Sexy.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilIsSexy)  (Warning: TV Tropes.)  Also, [Draco in Leather Pants.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DracoInLeatherPants)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Evil may be sexy, but I always thought that applied to the powerful-and-owning-it embracing-the-darkness mysterious-yet-unrestrained variety. Draco is more of a chronic-failure trying-to-please-dad loud-yet-cowardly type. I'd say Tom Felton's good looks have a lot more to do with this.

Comment: @MishaR, you could be right - according to TV Tropes it only dates back to circa 2005, *after* the first few movies came out.

Comment: @HarryJohnston He's not just Evil, he's also *Rich* - and have you seen what that did for Andrew Lloyd-Webber's prospects?

Comment: Barring any obvious deformities or problems with e.g. hygiene, is it really meaningful to talk about how "good looking" 11 year old kids are? The attractiveness of facial and other features changes a lot during puberty and only in the very last books any in-universe observations would be relevant.

Comment: I.e. you can reasonably argue about how good looking Tom Felton appears in most of the films, but I'd argue that in the first film (where the actor is already a couple years older than the character) it's *not* clear how good-looking Tom Felton is going to be.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I always got the impression that Hermione was average to slightly above average looking, with good features (aside from her teeth), but generally doesn't put any effort into her appearance. That's based on the fact that the one time she did (Yule Ball), she got noticed by guys.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Draco isn’t described as attractive *or* ugly.

Draco isn’t usually described as either good or bad looking. The best indication of what Draco was supposed to look like in the books is this drawing by J.K. Rowling.

[image]

He’s mainly described as having a pale pointed face with cold grey eyes and white-blond hair, without any mention of how attractive he is.  While the books are written in the third person, they reflect Harry’s view, so it’s unclear if the word choice is colored by that. The terms “pale and pointed” may have a slightly negative association, but whether those features make him look attractive or unattractive isn’t ever stated, so it can’t be assumed from that description. Kreacher does say he has “fine bones”, but as he misses the Black family, he is likely predisposed to think well of Draco.

> “Master Malfoy moves with a nobility that befits his pure blood,’ croaked Kreacher at once. ‘His features recall the fine bones of my mistress and his manners are those of –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 21 (The Unknowable Room)*</sup></sub>

His description remains consistent throughout the series. In the first book, Draco is described as having a pale, pointed face.

> "In the back of the shop, a boy with a pale, pointed face was standing on a footstool while a second witch pinned up his long black robes. Madam Malkin stood Harry on a stool next to him, slipped a long robe over his head and began to pin it to the right length." 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone)*</sup></sub>

He’s mentioned as having identically cold and grey eyes as his father.

> "The man who followed could only be his father. He had the same pale, pointed face and identical cold grey eyes." 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*</sup></sub>

He’s again described as having a pale and pointed face in “Chamber of Secrets”.

> "And from behind the six large figures before them came a seventh, smaller boy, smirking all over his pale, pointed face. It was Draco Malfoy." 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*</sup></sub>

Further descriptions of him tend to focus on a combination of these same features.

> "It was Draco Malfoy. He had pushed to the front of the crowd, his cold eyes alive, his usually bloodless face flushed, as he grinned at the sight of the hanging, immobile cat." 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*</sup></sub>

His face is also described as sneering in “Prisoner of Azkaban”, in addition to being pale and pointed.

> "Draco Malfoy and Harry had been enemies ever since they had met on their very first train journey to Hogwarts. Malfoy, who had a pale, pointed, sneering face, was in Slytherin house." 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*</sup></sub>

Through the years as he gets older, the description of Draco stays the same.

> "The Gryffindor team laughed loudly. Malfoy’s pale eyes narrowed, and he stalked away." 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*</sup></sub>

It’s mentioned that his mother Narcissa would be attractive if she didn’t look so haughty, but no observations are made on Draco’s attractiveness.

> "Harry and Draco Malfoy had been enemies ever since their very first journey to Hogwarts. A pale boy with a pointed face and white-blond hair, Draco greatly resembled his father. His mother was blonde, too; tall and slim, she would have been nice looking if she hadn’t been wearing a look that suggested there was a nasty smell under her nose." 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*</sup></sub>

Draco is also consistently described as looking like his father.

> "‘Manners, Potter, or I’ll have to give you a detention,’ drawled Malfoy, whose sleek blond hair and pointed chin were just like his father’s. ‘You see, I, unlike you, have been made a prefect, which means that I, unlike you, have the power to hand out punishments.’" 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*</sup></sub>

The same words are used to describe Draco throughout the series, from his introduction to his later years.

> "A teenage boy with a pale, pointed face and white-blond hair appeared from behind the rack wearing a handsome set of dark green robes that glittered with pins around the hem and the edges of the sleeves. He strode to the mirror and examined himself; it was a few moments before he noticed Harry, Ron and Hermione reflected over his shoulder. His light grey eyes narrowed." 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*</sup></sub>

At no point is it mentioned how attractive he is - he’s simply described as having white-blond hair and a pale pointed face.

> "Harry did not dare look directly at Draco, but saw him obliquely: a figure slightly taller than he was, rising from an armchair, his face a pale and pointed blur beneath white-blond hair." 
> <sub><sup>*-  Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*</sup></sub>

In Deathly Hallows, Draco’s face is also described as usually languid, but that may have only be since he became a Death Eater.

> "‘Of course not, of course not!’ said Lucius impatiently. He approached Harry himself, came so close that Harry could see the usually languid, pale face in sharp detail even through his swollen eyes. With his face a puffy mask, Harry felt as though he was peering out from between the bars of a cage." 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*</sup></sub>

Even in the epilogue, Draco is described as having a pointed chin and a receding hairline.

> "Draco Malfoy was standing there with his wife and son, a dark coat buttoned up to his throat. His hair was receding somewhat, which emphasised the pointed chin." 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*</sup></sub>

Throughout the series, Draco is never canonically stated to be either attractive or unattractive.

Comment: Is "pointed" and "pale" maybe meant to convey a negative judgment?

Comment: @Adamant It’s possible, and it seems likely, but I don’t think it’s clear enough to say for certain.

Comment: In the second-to-last quote, isn't it Lucius who is described as having a languid face?

Comment: @adamant I'm sure they are, but if Twilight's taught us anything...

Comment: @Adamant Or perhaps to evoke the "bishie" stereotype?  Pale face, pointed chin, white hair - Sephiroth much?

Comment: An interesting point to add here - the only characters whose attractiveness is mentioned by narration in the books are female, and (so far as I recall) there are only 3 chapters which follow or mention internal thoughts of a character who is *not* Harry (the first Chapters of "the Philosopher's Stone", Vernon Dursley and Prof. McGonagall; "The Goblet of Fire", Frank Bryce; and "The Half-Blood Prince", the Prime Minister).  So, the implication is that the attractiveness of characters mentioned is how *Harry* sees them.

Comment: @Chronocidal - We hear a bit about how ugly Crabbe and Goyle are.

Comment: @Chronocidal And to relate that specifically to Draco, while terms like "pointed" may not be used to mean physically unattractive, they are often used to describe someone when they have a cold or unwelcoming personality (more favourable words may include having "sharp" features or a "defined bone structure").

Comment: IMHO the author felt that Draco was in such a privileged position that his personal attractiveness simply didn't matter.

Comment: @Chronocidal there are several exceptions to that.  Cedric, Tom Riddle and Blaise Zabini are directly referred to as handsome.

Comment: @Chronocidal Incorrect. Percival Dumbledore, Cedric Diggory, Gilderoy Lockhart, James Potter, Sirius Black, Blaise Zabini, Tom Riddle and Bill Weasley are all described as good-looking or handsome. Even Ron is described as handsome by Slughorn. And that's not to mention Fawkes or Firenze.

Comment: Which one is Malfoy in the drawing?

Comment: @TheAsh I *did* specify "by narration", and you've listed a bunch of people described as such by dialogue instead...

Comment: @OrganicMarble - I second the question... none of them look "pointy" to me, though some of them having the angles of their attention be upward would make it hard to tell

Comment: So is _Lucius_ ever described as handsome? Draco is almost identical.

Answer (score 0):

I think he was supposed to be attractive, yes. Harry never thinks about him as being ugly even though they are enemies (not to encourage any of that Drarry fan fic stuff) and I can't think of anyone else ever describing him as "ugly" either. Tom Felton is obviously a fairly attractive fellow and I think book Draco is sort of supposed to be well. But either way I think it comes down to how you imagine him in the books but I do believe that he was supposed to be good looking.

Comment: Do you know of any text in the books specifically indicating that Draco is attractive? The absence of statements that he's _ugly_ doesn't necessarily mean he's attractive. He could just be very average in looks.